# Rewrite URL in WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to change URL from

```
//kidandtrip.loc/attractions?order_by=date&order_type=desc&view_type=gallery&page=1&keyword=**vie**&destination=**Salzburg**&sightseeing=**sightseeing**&museum=**museum**&qodef_tours_search_submit=Search
```

to

`//kidandtrip.loc/attractions/vie/Salzburg/sightseeing/museum`

I have tried to do it  using .htaccess, but it doesn't work. There is the line from my .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule
^attractions/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /attractions?order_by=date&order_type=desc&view_type=gallery&page=1&keyword=$1&destination=$2&sightseeing=$3&museum=$4&qodef_tours_search_submit=Search [L]
```

Could you help me? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit long, but you can use this `(^//kidandtrip\.loc/attractions).*?keyword=(\w+).*?destination=(\w+).*?sightseeing=(\w+).*?museum=(\w+)`

Basically you just ignore the full match and concatenate each capture group with a `/` in between.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYJy9Y/1)

Comment: I  have added this code to .htaccess 

RewriteRule (^//kidandtrip\.loc/attractions).*?keyword=(\w+).*?destination=(\w+).*?sightseeing=(\w+).*?museum=(\w+) [L]

But it also doesn't work

Comment: I'm not familiar with how RewriteRule works, but I explained how this would work. The full match will be everything up until your museum field. If you aren't able to break it into groups and concatenate them then this method won't work.

Comment: `group1 + "/" + group2 + "/" + group3 + "/" + group4 + "/" + group5` was what I was thinking